# What Can I remove from a kendo UI MVC project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've just converted an existing MVC 5 project to use Kendo UI. It has added a *lorry load* of files.

The application does not have to support other cultures (and least not in the foreseeable future).

Can I *safely* remove the files in `messages` and `cultures` folders that I'm not going to need?

If I am planning to use all of the components, can I just keep the `kendo.all.min.*` files and remove those associated with the individual components?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answers are: Yes and yes. Remove all cultures you don't need, that I can assure you.

Now, the question about `kendo.all.min` I'm not so sure, but according to [this doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need):

> The kendo.all.min.js contains a minified version of all features provided by Kendo UI.

So I believe it will work with only that resource.